# How to fit 2 gauss in python

Tags: python, csv, curve-fitting, amplitude, gauss

I am a new user of Python. I am trying to fit 2 Gaussians with data but there are some errors in the results.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
from scipy import optimize
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
from matplotlib import gridspec
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
%matplotlib inline

data = np.loadtxt('csv/test_run09.csv', encoding="utf-8", delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
x = data[:,1]
y1 = data[:,2]
y2 = data[:,3]
y3 = data[:,4]
y4 = data[:,5]
y5 = data[:,6]
y6 = data[:,7]
y7 = data[:,8]
y8 = data[:,9]
y9 = data[:,10]
y10 = data[:,11]
y11 = data[:,12]
y12 = data[:,13]
y13 = data[:,14]
y14 = data[:,15]

amp1 = 2
sigma1 = 0.1
x_array = x[(x>33)&(x<34)]
y_array = y14[(x>33)&(x<34)]

amp2 = np.max(y_array)
sigma2 = np.std(x_array)

def _1gaussian1(x_array, amp1, sigma1):
    return amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-\  33.49290958)/sigma1)**2))) + 0.2
def _1gaussian2(x_array, amp2, sigma2):
    return amp2*(1/(sigma2*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-\    33.6312849)/sigma2)**2))) + 0.2

popt_gauss1, pcov_gauss1 = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(_1gaussian1, x_array, y_array,     p0=[amp1, sigma1])
popt_gauss2, pcov_gauss2 = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(_1gaussian2, x_array, y_array,     p0=[np.max(y_array), np.std(x_array)])

def _2gaussian(x_array, amp1, sigma1, amp2, sigma2):
    return amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-    33.49290958)/sigma1)**2))) + amp2*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-33.6312849)/sigma2)**2))) + 0.3

popt_2gauss, pcov_2gauss = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(_2gaussian, x_array, y_array,         p0=[amp1, sigma1, np.max(y_array), np.std(x_array)])
perr_2gauss = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov_2gauss))
print(popt_2gauss)

pars_1 = popt_2gauss[0:2]
pars_2 = popt_2gauss[2:4]
gauss_peak_1 = _1gaussian1(x_array, *pars_1)
gauss_peak_2 = _1gaussian2(x_array, *pars_2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
plt.grid()

ax1.plot(x_array, y_array, "ro")
ax1.plot(x_array, _2gaussian(x_array, *popt_2gauss), 'k--')#,\

# # peak 1
ax1.plot(x_array, gauss_peak_1, "g")
ax1.fill_between(x_array, gauss_peak_1.min(), gauss_peak_1, facecolor="green",         alpha=0.5)

# # peak 2
ax1.plot(x_array, gauss_peak_2, "y")
ax1.fill_between(x_array, gauss_peak_2.min(), gauss_peak_2, facecolor="yellow",\                  alpha=0.5)  

# prints the fitting parameters with their errors
print("-------------Peak 1-------------")
print("amplitude = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_1[0], perr_2gauss[0]))
print("sigma = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_1[1], perr_2gauss[1]))
print("area = %0.2f" % np.trapz(gauss_peak_1))
print("-------------Peak 2-------------")
print("amplitude = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_2[0], perr_2gauss[2]))
print("sigma = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_2[1], perr_2gauss[3]))
print("area = %0.2f" % np.trapz(gauss_peak_2))
```

This is the result. I can plot the gauss fitting but the 2nd gauss seems to be wrong because the shape is much larger than the data. What should I do in this case?

[image]

Comment: For this to be reproducible please include data

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j3RmzKK0gh6vtMP9sjWxyJsGz2hW6oBG/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Sorry bro, this is the raw data

Comment: The difference between the first and second gaussians seems to be where you've hard-coded the time offset to be. These should not use magic numbers inside of your `gaussian` functions; they should have well-defined constants. But how did you arrive at them? Were they time offsets directly from your instrumentation?

Comment: What units does 'y' have?

Comment: The vertical axis is diffraction intensity (arb. units). I want to fit the gauss with the specific position so I put these parameters as the magic numbers in the gauss function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rewrite `_1gaussian2` as a near-identical implementation of `_1gaussian1`.

Don't hard-code your time offsets - unless these come from real experimental settings, leave them as degrees of freedom for your fit. Same for the 0.2 vertical offset.

Don't throw away your power data (the column headings). If I interpret them correctly, they're positive or negative power in milliwatts.

Do a parametric fit for every power level; you'll see that the parameters you had fixed should actually be variable.

Don't hard-code the slice 33-34. Use the whole data. Model the function as a simultaneous sum of two Gaussians.

```
import re
from typing import Iterator

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


sqrt2pi = np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)


def parse_power(filename: str) -> Iterator[float]:
    pat = re.compile(r'(neg|pos)_(\d+)_(\d+)mW')
    with open(filename) as f:
        header = next(f)
        for match in pat.finditer(header):
            magnitude = 1e-3 * float(match.expand(r'\2.\3'))
            if match.group(1) == 'neg':
                yield -magnitude
            else:
                yield magnitude


def gaussian(theta: np.ndarray, amp: float, offx: float, sigma: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return amp * np.exp(-0.5 * ((theta - offx) / sigma)**2)


def double_gaussian(
    theta: np.ndarray,
    amp1: float, amp2: float,
    offx1: float, offx2: float,
    sigma1: float, sigma2: float,
    offy: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return (
        offy
        + gaussian(theta, amp1, offx1, sigma1)
        + gaussian(theta, amp2, offx2, sigma2)
    )


def main() -> None:
    filename = 'test_run09.csv'
    powers = np.array(tuple(parse_power(filename)))
    order = powers.argsort()
    powers = powers[order]
    data = np.loadtxt(filename, encoding="utf-8", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
    theta = data[:, 1]
    # Sort columns by power
    data[:, 2:] = data[:, 2:][:, order]

    amp01 = 3
    amp02 = 9
    offx01 = 32.2
    offx02 = 33.5
    sigma01 = 0.1
    sigma02 = 0.1
    offy0 = 0.2
    init = (amp01, amp02, offx01, offx02, sigma01, sigma02, offy0)

    parameters = np.empty((len(powers), len(init)))

    for j in range(2, data.shape[1]):
        y = data[:, j]

        result, _ = curve_fit(
            f=double_gaussian,
            xdata=theta,
            ydata=y,
            p0=init,
        )
        parameters[j-2, :] = result

        def each_fit_plot():
            plt.figure()
            plt.scatter(theta, y)
            plt.plot(theta, double_gaussian(theta, *result), 'orange')
        # each_fit_plot()

    def plot_param(ylabel, start, end):
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(powers, parameters[:, start:end])
        plt.title('Parameters, first and second Gaussian pulse')
        plt.xlabel('Power')
        plt.ylabel(ylabel)

    plot_param('Amplitude', 0, 2)
    plot_param('Peak time', 2, 4)
    plot_param('Sigma', 4, 6)
    plot_param('Shared vertical offset', 6, 7)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: parameters]

[image: Curve fit]

If you generalise to a pseudogaussian pulse replacing **2 with abs()**p, the fit improves greatly:

[image: pseudogaussian]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will re-check the code again. Best